# Slim with embedded Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I decided to try out the .slim (slim template engine) since I don't like .erb and I also want to take the time to learn something that might prove useful in the long run.

Since I am at the same time following rails_tutorial I came to the part where `yield(:title)` is used

With .erb it looks like this:

```
<title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
```

With .slim I managed to make it look like:

```
title
  => yield(:title)
  | | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App
```

Now, what I want to do is to be able to type it in a single line. So is there a way to do that using .slim?

Here is another example I can't seem to make one line

```
a<> href="http://www.railstutorial.org/" 
  em Ruby on Rails Tutorial
```

Probably down the line I will not even do something like this but at this point in 
order to better learn I would like some pointers in regards to .slim.

The other question in order to prevent more questions like this is, where can I find a detailed documentation or tutorials with examples such as these.

FOLLOW-UP:

How would I then convert this:

```
 <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>">
    <%= message%>  
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Ok I think I have understood it:

```
 - flash.each do |message_type, message|
    .alert class="alert-#{message_type}"
      = message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag followed by text will output that text as the tag's contents. You can use string interpolation `#{expression}` inside the text to output variables.

Content text with a variable interpolated:

```
title #{yield(:title)} | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App
```

You can also set the tag's contents to a ruby expression by using `tag =`.

```
title = yield(:title) + " | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
```

Note that in this case this won't work if `yield(:title)` returns `nil`

When you have nested tags, you should put them on seperate lines.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.